# Changing UIImage when device orientation change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiimage

How can I change the background image whenever the device orientation changes ?

Comment: You mean different viewController's background image for different orientations?

Answer (score 2):

Change the image in your UIViewController's `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method.

Answer (score 0):

you can handle this in

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```